# Django admin aggregation

Tags: python, django, admin, aggregation

I'm using Django to manage deposit，but I found a problem, there is a medel looks like:

```
class Deposit(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
      money_re = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
      ...
```

I want to add a sum of money_re in the model to the admin change_list page in the right-bottom of the page.

Is there any way to use model aggregation in the admin change_list page

any helpful advise is welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `ModelAdmin.changelist_view()` and populate context with desired data:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class DepositAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        aggregates = Deposit.objects.aggregate(Sum('money_re'))
        context = {'total_deposit': aggregates['money_re__sum']}
        if extra_context:
            context.update(extra_context)
        return super(DepositAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, context)
```

Then create template `admin/<appname>/deposit/change_list.html` and show this data after the result list:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}

{% block result_list %}

    {{ block.super }}

    <div style="text-align: right; padding: 10px">
        Total deposit: <b>{{ total_deposit }}</b>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```